# CoreBluetooth keep class alive

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have made a viewController that handles CoreBluetooth methods I've written methods as changePass and changeName ... This viewController called BaseViewController has also alot of instance variables that I use through the connection. If I try to make an object from BaseViewController I lose the variables if I don't send them by segue to the secondViewControler.

Is there anyway I could keep the BaseViewController  alive and open secondViewController on top of it without losing variables in BaseViewController.

Comment: How are you transitioning from the first to the second view controller? Can you show some code?  In most cases the first view controller is still around, you just need to pass a reference to it to your second view controller.  You should also consider your application design and whether these variables would be better moved to another object class that can be referenced by both view controllers.

Comment: i see that again and again.. a VIEWcontrollers is a VIEWcontroller and not made to live forever!

Comment: Move the code into a singleton model manager maybe

Comment: @Paulw11 I transition using Modal or Push and I am using prepareForSegue to send variables, yet there are soo many variables so I need another solution.

Comment: Create an object class with properties for all of those variables. Then you can simply instantiate an instance of that class and pass that reference, or if it needs to be referenced from many other classes consider a singleton